# Access to consecutive features in PyQGIS loop

Tags: pyqgis

I have a point shapefile and I want to calculate the radius of the circle passing through three consecutive point and append it to the line that passing through two consecutive points.

For this, I'm using `circleAngleBetween()` method of `QgsGeometryUtils` class. It takes 3 points in class  `QgsPoint` as input.
Because I don't know how to access `geometry` (or any other attribute) of next or feature after next feature, I created two copies of my data and deleted first feature of my first copy and two first features of my second feature and used them in my code.

My code is

```
def get_name(o):
    return o['id']
path1 = "path/to/file.shp"


vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(path1, "layer1", "ogr")
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
path2 = "path/to/file.shp"


vvlayer = QgsVectorLayer(path2, "layer2", "ogr")
if not vvlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vvlayer)
path3 = "path/to/file.shp"


vvvlayer = QgsVectorLayer(path3, "layer3", "ogr")
if not vvvlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vvvlayer)
vlayer.startEditing()
features = sorted(vlayer.getFeatures(),key = get_name)
featuress = sorted(vvlayer.getFeatures(),key = get_name)
featuresss = sorted(vvvlayer.getFeatures(),key = get_name)
capa = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:32639", "temp", "memory")

pr = capa.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes([QgsField("codigo",  QVariant.Double)])
capa.updateFields()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(capa)

capa.startEditing()
for f,u,c in zip(features,featuress,featuresss):
    geom = f.geometry()
    point = geom.asPoint()
    pt1 = QgsPoint(point.x(),point.y())
    geom2 = u.geometry()
    point2 = geom2.asPoint()
    pt2 = QgsPoint(point2.x(),point2.y())
    geom3 = c.geometry()
    point3 = geom3.asPoint()
    pt3 = QgsPoint(point3.x(),point3.y())
    radu = QgsGeometryUtils.circleCenterRadius(pt1, pt2, pt3)[0]
    f.setAttribute(f.fieldNameIndex('rad'), radu)
    vlayer.updateFeature(f)
    feats = QgsFeature(capa.fields())
    feats.setAttribute("codigo", radu) 
    feats.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([QgsPointXY(point.x(),point.y()),
                                                 QgsPointXY(point2.x(),point2.y())]))
    capa.addFeature(feats) 
capa.endEditCommand()
```

As you can see, in the loop, first feature of 3rd layer is the same of 3rd feature of first layer and so on.
This works and the result are exactly what I want but I think there should be a way that takes just one point layer and with access to information of n+1'th feature and n+2'th feature in loop I can reach this result.

Am I right?

Comment: It is not the most memory efficient method, but I often store the getFeature() iterator as a list, and then use an enumerator to get features relative to the current one.

`for i,x in enumerate(features_list): next_feature = features_list[i+1] ## do something with current feature (x) and next_feature`.

You have to make a check that `i+1` does not exceed the number of features of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this script:

```
path1 = "path/to/file.shp"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(path1, "layer1", "ogr")
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

capa = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:32639", "temp", "memory")
capa.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("codigo",  QVariant.Double)])
capa.updateFields()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(capa)

# get the sorted feature list
fs = sorted(vlayer.getFeatures(), key=lambda o: o["id"])

vlayer.startEditing()
capa.startEditing()

# skipped the last two points, not to get IndexError.
for i in range(len(fs[:-2])):
    p1 = fs[i].geometry().asPoint()
    pt1 = QgsPoint(p1.x(), p1.y())

    p2 = fs[i+1].geometry().asPoint()
    pt2 = QgsPoint(p2.x(), p2.y())

    p3 = fs[i+2].geometry().asPoint()
    pt3 = QgsPoint(p3.x(), p3.y())

    radu = QgsGeometryUtils.circleCenterRadius(pt1, pt2, pt3)[0]
    fs[i].setAttribute(fs[i].fieldNameIndex('rad'), radu)
    vlayer.updateFeature(fs[i])

    feats = QgsFeature(capa.fields())
    feats.setAttribute("codigo", radu)
    feats.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([QgsPointXY(p1.x(), p1.y()),
                                                  QgsPointXY(p2.x(), p2.y())]))
    capa.addFeature(feats)

capa.commitChanges()
vlayer.commitChanges()
```